# Taking action depending on the presence of particular message in the echo area

Tags: latex, auctex, error-handling, echo-area, message

I have my proper function to run latex, say `my-tex`.
Sometimes one should run latex two times to get references right. A message like below in the echo area appears to tell this. How to identify programmatically the presence of this message in order that I run `my-tex` two times?

```
You should run LaTeX again to get references right, {14} pages
```

Comment: Perhaps by advising the `message` function? But I would try to get the information from elsewhere.

Comment: You should *not* be listening to the echo area, but instead be listening to the process running in the background using a process filter.  There are already process filters in existence with AUCTex.  Unfortunately, that library is so darn complex, you need a forum participant like Giordano to guide you further.  I use my own function with `start-process` that calls `latexmk.pl` and have my own process filter without using AUCTeX, so for me it would be a lot easier because I have just one filter and I know right were it is.  To get a head start, look for the process filters in AUCTeX.

Comment: To learn more about process filters, see the related section in the manual:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html

Comment: I agree with other comments above, it's better not to read the echo area.  You may want to define your own [sentinel](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html).  Take a look to `TeX-LaTeX-sentinel`.  After you define you're own sentinel function, set `TeX-sentinel-default-function` to the name of that function in LaTeX buffers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you want to accomplish exactly, but as other people pointed out, reading the echo area is not the best strategy.  Instead, you probably want to set up a [sentinel](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html).

Many commands in AUCTeX have a sentinel associated.  For example, the one associated to LaTeX command is `TeX-LaTeX-sentinel`.  You may want to build your own sentinel upon this one.  Once you define your sentinel function, you can set it as the default one by setting `TeX-sentinel-default-function` to the name's symbol of the function in LaTeX buffers (you can use a hook for this).

Comment: The sentinel itself is not going to help match/catch a process string output of:  "*You should run LaTeX again to get references right, {14} pages*".  My assumption, based on the question above, is that the OP may want to run LaTeX again if a similar message is generated by the running process.  For that, a process filter will be needed along with a `string-match` or something similar -- the page length will vary, so a `string-equal` would not be the best approach.

Comment: Of course this solution doesn't catch the string from the echo area, but replaces the function that emits that message.

Comment: The a new or redefined sentinel does *not* replace the function that emits the message.  A process filter is what catches the message, and it is used *in conjunction with* a sentinel:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html  A sentinel will only emit strings like:  "**finished\n**"; "**deleted\n**"; "**exited abnormally with code exitcode (core dumped)\n**" -- the “**core dumped**” part is *optional*, and *only* appears if the process dumped core; "**failed with code fail-code\n**"; "**signal-description (core dumped)\n**".

Comment: I'm merely explaining how things work in AUCTeX: the process filter only prepares a static buffer that is afterwards parsed by the sentinel, which then emits warnings to echo area and decides what to do based on what is present in the output buffer.  See http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=blob;f=tex-buf.el;h=d9648f8f51a5b99fb84fdda7393c06f9e9c421cc;hb=HEAD#l1493 if you don't believe me.  If the OP wants to exploit facilities already present in AUCTeX, then should hack the sentinel, if instead wants to write something from scratch then should write process-filter + sentinel.